# Hold out in R and k fold

Tags: r, machine-learning, cross-validation

I have a question, I'm wondering if the holdout function in R is a k fold cross validation ? It seems to be the same with the parameter "hldSettings" thing but I am not sure.

for example :

```
holdOut(learner('my_learner',
                         pars=list(Threshold=0.2,
                                   statsProds=globalStats)),
                 dataset(target_to_predict,my_dataset),
                 hldSettings(10,0.3,1234,T),
                 itsInfo=TRUE
```

)

Thank you for your answers :)

Comment: What package is `holdOut` a part of?

Comment: Package:  DMwR @user777

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A useful way to learn about what an R function does is to consult the documentation. Entering `?holdOut` into the console, we can see

> The idea of this function is to carry out a hold out experiment of a given learning system on a given data set. The goal of this experiment is to estimate the value of a set of evaluation statistics by means of the hold out method. Hold out estimates are obtained by randomly dividing the given data set in two separate partitions, one that is used for obtaining the prediction model and the other for testing it. This learn+test process is repeated k times. In the end the average of the k scores obtained on each repetition is the hold out estimate.

But in this case, it's not a $k$-fold CV since it does not specify that the method uses $k$ partitions. Instead, we have a train/test split repeated $k$ times at random. The difference is that $k$-fold CV would create $k$ splits of the same size, and iterate $k$ times between leaving out one partition, whereas in this method, the data set is split into train/holdout sets randomly each of $k$ times, so there is positive probability that two holdout sets will contain the same observations. By contrast, all holdout sets in $k$-fold CV are mutually disjoint.

Comment: Ok, is it good to evaluate a model ? @user777

Comment: @Peter That's really a different question that's worth posting in its own right. But perhaps someone has answered it already -- try searching our archives first. If you've found this answer helpful, please consider upvoting it.